# Kentico - Duplicate contacts getting created

Tags: kentico

We are working on Kentico 10.

We import contacts provided to us as CSV (saving in OM_Contact table).

Then our system sends emails to these users, they come to our website and register themselves.

The problem is that we are seeing duplicate contacts (not users) getting generated.

It looks like the first contact is created when we imported and second when user is registered (which also creates contact).

How can we make sure user registration associates the user to existing contact and not creating a new contact.

The code to create user is something like this:

```
UserInfo user = new UserInfo();

user.set ... ....

UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(user); 
UserInfoProvider.AddUserToSite(user.Email, SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend importing those contacts through the Kentico UI vs. writing code or importing directly into the database table.  In v10 there isn't much for duplicate checking but you can use the Merge tool to merge 2 contacts together.

Also, you need to be sure what you're talking about.  You reference the `OM_Contact` table.  This is a contact.  Then you showed code pointing at the `UserInfoProvider`.  This is a user account, someone who would log into a site.  A user can be tied to a contact via the `ContactUserID` field in the `OM_Contact` table.  So maybe having a better understanding of exactly what you're talking about would be the first step.

Duplicate question posted directly on [Kentico's DevNet here](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/duplicate-contacts-are-getting-created).